# Logistic regression in python Erorr: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'concavity_worst'

Tags: python, data-science, logistic-regression

I'm trying to make a simple logistic regression program for a dataset that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NV5TM.jpg
[image]

My program should use logistic regression on the dataset, and output some info about the results of the regression. Using an example I made this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

import pandas as pd
col_names = ['id', 'diagnosis', 'radius_mean', 'texture_mean', 'perimeter_mean', 'area_mean', 'smoothness_mean','compactness_mean', 'symmetry_se', 'perimeter_worst', 'smoothness_worst', 'concavity_worst']

# load dataset
data = pd.read_csv("DatasetTest.csv", header=None, names=col_names)
data.head()

feature_cols = ['diagnosis', 'radius_mean','texture_mean','perimeter_mean','area_mean', 'smoothness_mean','compactness_mean', 'symmetry_se', 'perimeter_worst','smoothness_worst', 'concavity_worst']
X = data[feature_cols]
y = data.diagnosis

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.25,random_state=0)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred=logreg.predict(X_test)

from sklearn import metrics
cnf_matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
cnf_matrix
```

When running the code this error occurs:

> could not convert string to float: 'concavity_worst'

Couldn't find a similar problem on stackoverflow. After doing research I found the function fit() apparently can't take strings. But I'm not sure how to convert the strings to floats. After doing some googling I still couldn't find a solution working for this situation.

Example used for the code: https://towardsdatascience.com/a-beginners-guide-to-linear-regression-in-python-with-scikit-learn-83a8f7ae2b4f

Comment: What does `data.dtypes` output?

Comment: @OllieinPGH  this outputs the following:
diagnosis             int64, 
radius_mean           int64, 
texture_mean        float64, 
perimeter_mean      float64, 
area_mean           float64, 
smoothness_mean     float64, 
compactness_mean    float64, 
symmetry_se         float64, 
perimeter_worst     float64, 
smoothness_worst    float64, 
concavity_worst     float64, 
dtype: object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) of `pd.read_csv`, you need to

> Explicitly pass header=0 to be able to replace existing names

If you don't, it will take the file header as part of the data. So, now all your column names are mixed with your data, and all of your columns contain a string. That will crash the regression because it can't take strings as input.